# Use jest to mock third-party-package method that need to initializes an object instance of a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to use jest to mock the method 'sendBatch' from third-party-package: '[messaging-api-messenger](https://github.com/bottenderjs/messaging-apis/tree/master/packages/messaging-api-messenger)' in my unit test.
My code:

```js
// sendMessages.js
async function sendMessage () {
  const { MessengerClient } = require('messaging-api-messenger')
  const client = new MessengerClient({accessToken: 'accessToken'})
  return client.sendBatch([{message:'message', to:'someone'}]
}
module.exports = sendMessage()
```

```js
// send.test.js
const Send = require('sendMessage')
const sendBatchMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {})
jest.mock('messaging-api-messenger', () => {
  return {
    MessengerClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      sendBatch: sendBatchMock
    }))
  }
})
sendBatchMock.mockReturnValue({
  success: true,
  responseData: [{ code: 200, body: { } }]
})
it('send message' async () => {
  const sendResult = await Send.sendMessage()
  expect(sendResult).toEqual('what I want')
}
```

This is sendBatch actually return:

```
sendResult {
  success: true,
  responseData: [ { code: 400, headers: [Array], body: [Object] } ]
}
```

But I want sendBatch return this:

```
sendResult {
  success: true,
  responseData: [ { code: 200, headers: [], body: {} } ]
}
```

How do I mock sendBatch method which is called at sendMessage.js, and ask sendBatch method return specific values I want and check return values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const { MessengerClient } = require('messaging-api-messenger')
sinon.stub(MessengerClient.prototype, 'sendBatch').resolves([{ code: 200, headers: [], body: {} } ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sendMessage` function is not returning anything so `sendResult` variable will be undefined in this test:

```
const sendResult = await Send.sendMessage();
expect(sendResult).toEqual('what I want');
```

You could return from that function so would have:

```
async function sendMessage () {
  const { MessengerClient } = require('messaging-api-messenger')
  const client = new MessengerClient({accessToken: 'accessToken'})
  return client.sendBatch([{message:'message', to:'someone'}]
}
```

But then this would not make sense to test with

```
it('send message' async () => {
  const sendResult = await Send.sendMessage()
  expect(sendResult).toEqual('what I want')
}
```

You might want to check that you called `sendBatch` is called with the correct parameters. To do that please refer to [Jest Mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports) documentation.

You'd have something like:

```
import { sendMessage } from "../sendMessages";
const sendBatchMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});

jest.mock("messaging-api-messenger", () => {
  return {
    MessengerClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      sendBatch: sendBatchMock,
    })),
  };
});

describe("my test", () => {
  it("should call my method with the correct parameters", async () => {
    await sendMessage();
    expect(sendBatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      { message: "message", to: "someone" },
    ]);
  });
});
```

And if you still want to check the result after mocking the returned value:

```
it("should work as well", async () => {
  sendBatchMock.mockReturnValue("what I want");

  expect(await sendMessage()).toEqual("what I want");
  expect(sendBatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
    { message: "message", to: "someone" },
  ]);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your sharing, but it doesn't work. I update my question, hope to get any suggestion. @Fcmam5